# Как реализовать на CSS смену двух DIV элементов (стоят друг за другом) поворотом вокруг оси Y

Tags: css

Хотелось понять как реализовать подобное 
https://exadel.com/services/mobile-app-development/
Поворот одного DIV и замена его вторым (невидимым в начале) на CSS?

Comment: Разъясните подробнее словами в тексте вопроса, что вам нужно, так как ссылка может в будущем измениться или перестать работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь это то, что Вам нужно.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #BBDEFB;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.front {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.back {
  background-color: #BDBDBD;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card:hover .front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card:hover .back {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front"><span>Front</span></div>
    <div class="back"><span>Back</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как тут тему закрыть подскажите?

Comment: @Виктор, никак, если Вас удовлетворил ответ, то ставите галочку напротив него, в будущем если у людей возникнет идентичный вопрос, то они смогут быстро найти ответ на него. Благодаря Вам!

Answer (score 1):

А просто посмотреть веб-инспектором на том сайте не получилось?

Контейнер. В нем два дива. Один под другим.

У нижнего стоит стиль `transform:rotateY(180deg)`, который поворачивает его относительно вертикальной оси.

У обоих стили `transition: transform 0.3s;` (делает так, чтобы поворачивалось не мгновенно) и `transform-style: preserve-3d;` (задает трехмерность трансформации; по умолчанию все в плоскости экрана).

При наведении мышой на контейнер отрабатывает стиль, убирающий трансформацию (`transform:rotateY(180deg)`) с нижнего дива и добавляющий ее для верхнего.

Comment: А как он реализует :hover? Может надо как-то по очереди запускать (:before, :after)? Не могу отыскать реализацию данного процесса :)

Comment: Щито? Это старый добрый CSS, работает типа так: `.container:hover div.first {transfrom:rotateY(180deg);} .container:hover div.second {transfrom:unset;} `